# Function for SortBy

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting

Let's say I have the following list

```
list = {{-1, 0, 0, 1}, {-1, 0, 1, 0}, {-1, 1, 0, 0}, {0, -1, 0, 1}, 
        {0, -1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, -1, 1}, {0, 0, 1, -1}, {0, 1, -1, 0}, 
        {0, 1, 0, -1}, {1, -1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, -1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, -1}}
```

What sort function (`sfunc`) used in `SortBy [list, sfunc]` can give me `slist`?

```
slist = {{0, 0, 1, -1}, {0, 0, -1, 1}, {0, -1, 0, 1}, {-1, 0, 0, 1}, 
         {0, 1, 0, -1}, {0, 1, -1, 0}, {0, -1, 1, 0}, {-1, 0, 1, 0},
         {1, 0, 0, -1}, {1, 0, -1, 0}, {1, -1, 0, 0}, {-1, 1, 0, 0}}
```

Few examples of sorted data

```
slist1 =  {{0, 0, 1, -2}, {0, 0, -2, 1}, {0, -2, 0, 1}, {-2, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0, -2}, {0, 1, -2, 0}, {0, -2, 1, 0}, {-2, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, -2}, {1, 0, -2, 0}, {1, -2, 0, 0}, {-2, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, -1, -1}, {0, -1, 1, -1}, {0, -1, -1, 1}, {-1, 0, 1, -1}, {-1, 0, -1, 1},{-1, -1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, -1, -1}, {1, -1, 0, -1}, {1, -1, -1, 0}, {-1, 1, 0, -1}, {-1, 1, -1, 0}, {-1, -1, 1, 0}}


slist2 = {{0, 0, 2, -2}, {0, 0, -2, 2}, {0, -2, 0, 2}, {-2, 0, 0, 2}, {0, 1, 1, -2}, {0, 1, -2, 1}, {0, -2, 1, 1}, {-2, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 2, 0, -2}, {0, 2, -2, 0}, {0, -2, 2, 0}, {-2, 0, 2, 0}, {1, 0, 1, -2}, {1, 0, -2, 1}, {1, -2, 0, 1}, {-2, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0, -2}, {1, 1, -2, 0}, {1, -2, 1, 0}, {-2, 1, 1, 0}, {2, 0, 0, -2}, {2, 0, -2, 0}, {2, -2, 0, 0}, {-2, 2, 0, 0}, {0, 2, -1, -1}, {0, -1, 2, -1}, {0, -1, -1, 2}, {-1, 0, 2, -1}, {-1, 0, -1, 2}, {-1, -1, 0, 2}, {1, 1, -1, -1}, {1, -1, 1, -1}, {1, -1, -1, 1}, {-1, 1, 1, -1}, {-1, 1, -1, 1}, {-1, -1, 1, 1}, {2, 0, -1, -1}, {2, -1, 0, -1}, {2, -1, -1, 0}, {-1, 2, 0, -1}, {-1, 2, -1, 0}, {-1, -1, 2, 0}}
```

Comment: Explain the core idea behind your sorted list.  It certainly isn't clear what you're seeking.

Comment: Can you give some examples with more complicated data?

Comment: @MikeY I have added  2 more sorted sets.

Comment: So if you sort your data like this, it can probably be counted and therefore indexed in closed form.

Comment: @MikeY Yes I have decided to use this sorting. I have edited by bounty question. If you have time then you could answer that, then I can gladly give you the bounty.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

EDITED TO ADD A SORT CRITERION
For the data sets, you are sorting on

1. the number of negative numbers first, then
2. the subset of just the nonnegative elements (using canonical ordering for lists), then
3. the set gained when you replace negative terms with a '1' and nonnegative with  '0'
4. The subset of just the negative elements (using canonical ordering)

   ```
    funkySort[list_]:= SortBy[list,{
                          Count[#, _?Negative] &,
                          Select[#, NonNegative] &,  
                          Negative,
                          Select[#, Negative] &
                          }]


   slist == funkySort[slist[[RandomPermutation[Length[slist]]]]]
   slist1 == funkySort[slist1[[RandomPermutation[Length[slist1]]]]]
   slist2 == funkySort[slist2[[RandomPermutation[Length[slist2]]]]]
   ```

> True
>
> True
>
> True

Comment: But  `slist != funkySort[list]` . Are you sure this works. It doesn't seem to work on my system. Do you get really get `slist1` and `slist2` when your function is applied to any random ordering of those lists.

Comment: Oops, copied over the wrong `funkySort[ ]` from my notebook. Fixed it...